# Error The SQL command for a FOR ALL ENTRIES select is too large

Tags: abap, opensql

The below statement is causing short dumps saying:

> The SQL command for a FOR ALL ENTRIES select is too large

So in the code below, the ranges tables all have the ranges table type. The runtime error caused is `DBSQL_FAE_STATEMENT_TO_BIG`. I'm not entirely sure what is causing it and how I can optimize it.

Note that I am already looping through a set of entries at a time for `it_tab2` and performing this select in a loop, so that to take care of the case where `it_tab2` is too big.

The number of entries in the ranges table also does not seem to be too much, which makes me wonder why it is causing a dump.

```
SELECT id numpeople APPENDING TABLE it_tab
  FROM workbook
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_tab1
  WHERE id    EQ it_tab1-id
    AND id    IN it_tab2
    AND lang  IN tab_ranges1
    AND name  IN tab_ranges2
    AND phone IN tab_ranges3
    AND fax   IN tab_ranges4.
```

Comment: The field "id" is used in the WHERE condition twice: Once in the FOR ALL ENTRIES, than again in the next line: "id IN it_tab2". This can be optimized: before the SELECT remove the entries from it_tab1 which are not in it_tab2. After that you don't need the "id IN it_tab2" condition

Comment: Most cases of `FOR ALL ENTRIES` can be solved more elegantly and performant using a `JOIN`. But to tell you how we would need to see where the content of `it_itab1` comes from.

Comment: Also, other possible solutions can be via an additional DDIC table to contain your internal table so that to use a join (any version), Global Temporary Table (ABAP 7.50), AMDP (HANA/7.40)...

Answer (score 1):

This limit coming from DB side. Every DB has limit for IN operator related by data size. You can try to use JOIN instead of FOR ALL ENTRIES. If there is no way you can split your itab to smaller pieces.

Answer (score 1):

The DB statement gets too large.
The FOR ALL ENTRIES is  converted to a mega SQL OR statement.

Use an alternate option like package fetch.

```
OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD l_index_c  FOR

      SELECT * FROM myTab
                  WHERE ...
                

    DO.
      FETCH  NEXT CURSOR  l_index_c INTO TABLE  lt_bla
             PACKAGE SIZE 1000.
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        EXIT.
      ENDIF.


     .... something with the data happens


    ENDDO.

    CLOSE CURSOR l_index_c.
```

[SAP Open Cursor / Fetch Docu and examples](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapopen_cursor.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this is caused because the internal table you are using is too large for the `FOR ALL ENTRIES` statement. This is slightly related to this post.

I found that the solution for this is processing the for all entries in batches. 5000 looks like a good rule of thumb, as the database limit is usually around 2000 ~ 10000 (See note [1156710](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1156710)).

Following your example:

```
CONSTANTS gc_records_batch_size TYPE i VALUE 5000.

TYPES:

BEGIN OF ty_tab1_id,
  batch TYPE RANGE OF tab1-id,
END OF ty_tab1_id.

DATA:
  lv_records_counter TYPE i.
  lt_batches         TYPE TABLE OF ty_tab1_id,
  ls_batch           LIKE LINE OF lt_batch_ranges,
  ls_id1_range       TYPE zrange. "Create your own range type of id1.


"Split it_tab1 into batches

LOOP AT it_tab1 INTO DATA(ls_tab1).
  ls_id1_range-sign  = 'I'.
  ls_id1_range-option = 'EQ'.
  ls_id1_range-low  = ls_tab1-id.

  APPEND ls_id1_range TO ls_batch-batch.

  ADD 1 TO lv_records_counter.

  IF lv_records_counter >= gc_records_batch_size. 
​    APPEND ls_batch TO lt_batches.
​    CLEAR: ls_batch, lv_records_counter.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP. 

"Add any remainder
IF ls_batch IS NOT INITIAL.
  APPEND ls_batch TO lt_batches.
ENDIF.   

LOOP AT lt_batches INTO ls_batch.
  SELECT id numpeople APPENDING TABLE it_tab
​    FROM workbook
​      WHERE id IN ls_batch-batch
​      AND id  IN it_tab2
​      AND lang IN tab_ranges1
​      AND name IN tab_ranges2
​      AND phone IN tab_ranges3
​      AND fax  IN tab_ranges4.

ENDLOOP.
```